# Could not count the date difference in minute using PHP

Tags: php

I am facing one issue. I need to calculate datetime difference using PHP but getting the wrong value. I am explaining my code below.

```
<?php
$added_date="31-01-2018 12:46 PM";
$endTime = strtotime("+10 minutes", strtotime($added_date));

$currentTime = strtotime(date("d-m-Y H:i:s A"));
//echo $currentTime.'</br>';
// (round(abs($currentTime - $endTime) / 60,2));exit;
if(round(abs($currentTime - $endTime) / 60,2) > 10){
    echo false;
}else{
    echo true;
}
?>
```

Here I need if current time is more than `10 min` from given date-time it will return false but its always showing `true`.

Comment: FWIW, `strtotime(date(...))` takes the current time, formats it to a string, then parses that string into a UNIX timestamp. That's super backasswards. Just do `time()` instead to get the current UNIX timestamp.

Comment: This correctly outputs `false` for me. https://3v4l.org/LAfDY

Comment: I am Getting False only

Comment: i am also getting false only.

Comment: Why is this off topic. He's requesting help with getting a true if T > 10 min and T <= 10 min should be a false as a result...

Comment: My answer: 
Use DateTime objects and use the diff method. 
This is what will do what you want. 
`$datetime1 = new DateTime('31-01-2018 11:46');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('31-01-2018 11:56');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
if ( $interval->i > 10){
 echo true;
} else {
 echo false;
}`

Comment: @Werner `->i` does not do what you think it does!

Comment: @deceze I know what you mean, as ->i could be 0 and there could be more significant properties (like days! being >0) making total time difference >> 10 mins. Thanks for pointing that out! (the if-statement should be expanded).

Comment: `strtotime(date("d-m-Y H:i:s A"))` doesn't return anything. It's likely that your `date()` call is returning a string that is not in the correct format for `strtotime()` to work. Thus, you're essentially doing `0 - $endTime`, which returns a much, much larger difference than you were anticipating. Fix the date format string and you should be good to go. Granted, I don't recommend the approach you're taking at all, but that's a different discussion altogether.

Comment: You could just do `if ( abs($currentTime - $endTime) > 600 )`

Comment: Figured it out! It's the actual date format that `strtotime` doesn't like. It won't parse a time with both a 24-hour hour (over 12) and a meridian (AM/PM). This is why some of us were seeing it work correctly and some weren't.

Answer (score 0):

I don't talk about logic of your code.

But the problem of your code is on calculate `$currentTime` var.

```
$currentTime = strtotime(date("d-m-Y H:i:s A"));
```

It return nothing! because the pattern bad used in `strtotime`.
You must use this:

```
$currentTime = strtotime(date("d-m-Y h:i:s A"));
```

Or this:

```
$currentTime = strtotime(date("d-m-Y H:i:s"));
```

For have correction timestramp in `$currentTime` var.

Comment: or the OP could just use `time()` to get current time.

Comment: @Anthony I know, but I wanna to bug fix, and I don't want to improve codes.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code isn't working is because `strtotime` does not like the fact that your date is formatted as `d-m-Y H:i:s A`. The reason it doesn't like this is because you have both the 24-hour version of the hour and the am/pm meridian indicator. There is no such thing as "15:00 PM" as far as `strtotime` is concerned. Either of the following will get you the datetime integer you need :

```
$currentTime = strtotime(date("d-m-Y h:i:s A")); // 07-02-2018 06:24:49 PM
```

or

```
$currentTime = strtotime(date("d-m-Y H:i:s"));  // 07-02-2018 18:28:42
```

or, if you just need the current time as an integer, you could avoid this altogether and use :

```
$currentTime = time();
```

Alternatively:

You could use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) object built into PHP

```
$added_date= "31-01-2018 12:46 PM";
$endTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i A', $added_date);
$endTime->modify("+10 minutes");

$currentTime = new DateTime();

$time_diff = $currentTime->diff($endTime, 1);

if ($time_diff->i > 10 ) {
    echo "true" . PHP_EOL;
} else if ( $time_diff->i == 10 && $time_diff->s > 0) {
    echo "true" . PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo "false" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Note that `DateTime::diff` returns a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object, which allows you to access the difference for different units.